# setOnClickListener en activity android

Tags: android

tengo un boton al cual le di un setOnClickListener en el onCreate estor recibiendo un intent que tiene un arrayList y el array list se actualiza cuando agrego mas imagenes.Quiero terminar el ciclo de vida de la app pero no me esta quedando. Cuando agrego mas imagenes selecciono el boton btnPicture entonces me manda a otra actividad donde en esta actividad tengo el del cancelar por si ya no quiere subir o el de seleccionar pero si le doy en cancelar llamo a Clase.superonBackPressed para regresar a la actividad pero cuando regresa ya esta destruida la actividad.

```
btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();//./<------------------------CHECAR
            Intent intentMain = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, MainActivity.class);//creo un intent
            startActivity(intentMain);//inicio la actividad

        }//./OnClick
    });//./OnClickLIstener

    btnPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentPicture = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, PictureActivity.class);//creo un intent
            intentPicture.putExtra("arrayImages", listOfImages);//le paso el arreglo como parametro
            startActivity(intentPicture);//inicio la actividad
            finish();//./<------------------------CHECAR
        }//./OnClick
    });//./OnClickListener
```

Comment: Cuando le de a btnHome destruir completamente todas las actividades

Answer (score 0):

Si llamas `finish()` la `Activity` en la que te encuentras se destruye.

Por lo tanto si llamas `finish()` y después realizas el `Intent` para abrir otra `Activity`, si deseas regresar a la `Activity` que realizo el `Intent`, esta ya no existirá ya que fue destruida.

```
finish();
Intent intentMain = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, MainActivity.class);//creo un intent
startActivity(intentMain);//inicio la actividad
```

---

Si tu duda es :

> Como recupero mi activity tal cual y como estaba

Te recomiendo no llames `finish()` , para que cuando llames `onBackPressed()` puedas regresar a tu `Activity` sin problema.

Comment: cuando le doy a btnPicture me manda a otra actividad y paso un array, en la actividad el usuario puede seleccionar imagenes y darle a una palomita donde lo mandara de nuevo a esta actividad pero tambien tiene una tache donde tengoun ImagesActivity.super.onBackPressed y regresa a esta actividad pero notaras que la actividad ya se destruyo.Mi duda es como recupero mi activity tal cual y como estaba

Comment: ve mi actualización , no llames finish(), comentame que resultado tienes.

Comment: Si lo entiendo pero si el usuario si selecciona imagenes tengo un intent entonces tendia 2 procesos sin destruir y puedo acceder a ellos picandole al boton atras del mobil

Comment: No te explicas nada bien, pon el código de la otra actividad

Comment: No llames finish(). No vas a tener 2 procesos. La actividad entra en pause y esta en el background.